# How to pass variables from VBScript to CMD?

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have an executable which I want to run from CMD with arguments.

I tried

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd strExePath  Mode  strPath strBase strResponse strLogPath"
```

When I run this script, it only opens CMD. What is the correct approach for passing arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need CMD for [running](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx) an executable from VBScript. Something like this should suffice:

```
oShell.Run "exepath arg1 arg2 ...", 0, True
```

If you must use CMD for some reason make sure to use one of the parameters `/c` (close CMD after execution) or `/k` (keep CMD open after execution).

```
oShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c exepath arg1 arg2 ...", 0, True
```

Note that either way VBScript only expands environment variables in the command string (e.g. `%COMSPEC%`), not VBScript variables. If you want to construct the command string using VBScript variables you need to use string concatenation:

```
exepath = "C:\path\to\your.exe"
oShell.Run """" & exepath & """ arg1 arg2 ...", 0, True
```

The additional double quotes are to take care of potential spaces in `exepath`.